# Wordpress создать галерею

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка

Привет всем, создаю галерею в wordpress, через добавить медиафайл / добавить галерею, вставляю изображение все вроде хорошо.

Но после того как обновляю страницу там нет никакой галерею а всего лишь надпись.

```
[gallery ids="1220,1211,1202"]
```

Может в коде верстки надо что - то вставить или я что то пропускаю ?

Comment: Шорткод не срабатывает. Вопрос, почему. Шаблон страницы кастомный наверняка?

Comment: все разобрался, дело было в том что the_content() показывает все, а вот get_post не хочет

Comment: Правильно, потому что the_content вызывает do_shortcode().

Comment: в итоге решил так   $post_content = get_post_gallery( $translate, true );

Comment: echo $post_content;